# MSChart axis lines

Tags: c#, mschart

How to show axis line for each bar in chart? I have line only on second, fourth ...,

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6106/chartiu.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6106/chartiu.png)

Comment: Thanks! Stuck with this for days!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 1;
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 1;
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
```

Now it looks like:

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/5818/chartig.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/5818/chartig.png)