# MSChart- draw a circle at top of bar in winforms

Tags: c#, mschart

i want to draw a circle at top of each column bar in a graph and draw dotted line from bar to x-axis.please refer my [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857115/mschart-axis-lines/8395783#8395783)
Please give your valuable comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a circle on top of the column bars you would need to add one more series of

`ChartType = Bubble` and then set `MarkerSize` and `MarkerStyle` properties, this will then show up as bubble on the columns once you bind them.

I am not sure of this second part of the dotted lines from X-Axis but from what i assume you should be happy by setting up these properties

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

These will show up as dotted lines from your X values across the ChartArea.

**EDIT**

you can also try setting up the MarkerStyle and MarkerSize property for the Column type series and it should show up circles on top of the column.

```
Chart1.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
Chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize = 5;
Chart1.Series[0].MarkerColor = Color.Blue;
```

This code should show a blue circle on top of your column.

Comment: Did you set the major grid or have you enabled staggered due to which its behaving differently

Comment: Its property of chart area no need to loop and assign it per point, just one line as in my answer is enough

Comment: its not working...                                  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

Comment: I see you have set `AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;` can you try removing that

Comment: its show in both side of center line(0). but i want dotted line below 0 to x-axis for all(Up & Down column bar).

Comment: i am not sure if that is possible, will update if i get anything similar