# Remove the second row in x-axe of Chart

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit

I use WPF toolkit Chart control. How to remove the second row in x-axe of Chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a second row, it's juste "space management" of labels. You must set another datetime format in order to let enough space for the rendering.

Comment: It will not have enough space with any datetime format. There are too many data.

Comment: As suggest by radbyx you can rotate labels (even in mschart), you can also show few labels :)

Comment: I don't want rotate labels. I want minimize height of x-axe.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857115/mschart-axis-lines . You must play with the Inverval property and other settings like this.

Comment: I did not find these properties (((

Comment: <ch:Chart><ch:AreaSeries ... /></ch:Chart> where in Chart should I use these properties?

Answer (score 0):

I working with Telerik RadChart and there you can rotate the labels, so if you use let's say an angle of 45, they will line up nicely without and overlap. Maybe it's possible to in your language? Try look for it, I would not be surprised if you could do the same.

Comment: It behavior related to width of Chart. When I'm expanding Chart it row is appear and when I continue expanding Chart it control is disappear.